Levi civita expression validity
So I have a question on if the following identity is true or false. It might be quite trivial but I think I've been going around in circles trying to prove/disprove it:
$$ \epsilon_{imn}\epsilon_{jqr} M_{mq}M_{nr} = \epsilon_{jmn}\epsilon_{iqr} M_{mq}M_{nr}.$$
(where $M$ is an arbitrary symmetric matrix though I think should not matter to us?)
I had previously tried using kronecker delta expansion (the determinant one). Maybe I should think simpler and plug in values instead of using indices?
Any help would be appreciated!

$\varepsilon_{123} \varepsilon_{231} \ne \varepsilon_{223} \varepsilon_{131}$ (sent before OP added contraction with matrices).

Ah yep mb, I should have added the contractions before hand!

@MarkViola $i$ and $j$ are free here, not being summed over.

yep i and j, are free indices not summed over

hmmm but i and j are not dummy indices? cause we are not summing over them so it should matter? @MarkViola

These are the same if $M$ are symmetric. Indeed, then \begin{align*}
\varepsilon_{imn} \varepsilon_{jqr} M_{mq} M_{nr}&= \varepsilon_{imn} \varepsilon_{jqr} M_{qm} M_{rn} \\
&= \varepsilon_{iqr} \varepsilon_{jmn} M_{mq} M_{nr},
\end{align*}
after relabelling $m \leftrightarrow q$ and $n \leftrightarrow r$.
This is not true in general if $M$ is not symmetric. Indeed, let $i=1$ and $j=2$. Then,\begin{align*}
&\varepsilon_{1mn} \varepsilon_{2qr} M_{mq} M_{nr} \\={}& \varepsilon_{123} \varepsilon_{213} M_{21} M_{33} + \varepsilon_{123} \varepsilon_{231} M_{23} M_{31} + \varepsilon_{132} \varepsilon_{213} M_{31} M_{23} + \varepsilon_{132} \varepsilon_{231} M_{33} M_{21} \\
={}& 2M_{23} M_{31} - 2 M_{21} M_{33}.
\end{align*}
But, \begin{align*}
&\varepsilon_{2mn} \varepsilon_{1qr} M_{mq} M_{nr} \\={}& \varepsilon_{213} \varepsilon_{123} M_{12} M_{33} + \varepsilon_{213} \varepsilon_{132} M_{13} M_{32} + \varepsilon_{231} \varepsilon_{123} M_{32} M_{13} + \varepsilon_{231} \varepsilon_{132} M_{33} M_{12} \\
={}& 2 M_{32} M_{13} - 2 M_{12} M_{33},
\end{align*}
and indeed these are equal if $M$ is symmetric.

AHHH yep I see so it did matter that it was symmetric thanks!! I can't upvote yet because Im new but appreciate the help!!

@AbdullahFouzudeen No problem! Glad it helped. If you found the answer helpful, I think you should still be able to accept it with the green tick.

And you should now have enough rep to upvote too :p Welcome to the site!
